# How to move sub-query where condition out of sub-query?

Tags: sql, oracle, join, subquery, outer-join

In Oracle I have a quite large select statement. I would like to save it as a view so that I can call it both from a .NET program and use it as the basis for some statistics, we have to generate. When using the view it's always filtered on a date.

I would like something like this:

```
select * from my_view
where my_view.date = '2014-01-01';
```

The problem is that I need to use the date as a parameter in the where condition of a subquery:

```
select * from table1
left outer join (
    select * from table2
    where table2.date = :somedate)
  on table1.Id = table2.Id;
```

... which cannot be made into a view.

Is there a way, that I can move the date comparision outside the sub-query without messing up the left outer join?

**What not to do:**

This creates an inner join - which is not what I want:

```
select * from table1
left outer join 
  table2
  on table1.Id = table2.Id
where table2.date = '2014-01-01';
```

This select filters out the rows in table1, that doesn't join on a row on the specified date, but does join on a row on another date:

```
select * from table1
left outer join 
  table2
  on table1.Id = table2.Id
where table2.Id is null
   or table2.date = '2014-01-01';
```

Comment: You probably want a table valued function rather than a view:  http://www.oracle-base.com/articles/misc/pipelined-table-functions.php.

Answer (score 1):

There are ways to parametrize views - for example using packages or application contexts (you can use built-in context CLIENTCONTEXT). But all these ways require the complete control over parameters and you have to set parameter values using additional functionality, this may be a serious drawback:

```
SQL> create or replace view param_view
  2  as
  3  select d.name, e.firstname, e.lastname, e.email
  4  from department d left join employee e
  5  on (d.id = e.departmentid
  6  and e.firstname = sys_context('CLIENTCONTEXT','EMPNAME'))
  7  /

View created.

SQL> exec dbms_session.set_context('CLIENTCONTEXT','EMPNAME','Scott')

PL/SQL procedure completed

SQL> select * from param_view;

NAME                 FIRSTNAME  LASTNAME             EMAIL                      
-------------------- ---------- -------------------- --------------------       
Department A         Scott      Tiger                xxx@gmail.com              
Department B                                                                    
Department C                                                                    

SQL> exec dbms_session.set_context('CLIENTCONTEXT','EMPNAME','Allen')

PL/SQL procedure completed

SQL> select * from param_view;

NAME                 FIRSTNAME  LASTNAME             EMAIL                      
-------------------- ---------- -------------------- --------------------       
Department A         Allen      Dirk                 yyy@gmail.com              
Department B                                                                    
Department C
```

or

```
SQL> create or replace package pck_test
  2  is
  3   function get return varchar2;
  4   procedure set (x in varchar2);
  5  end;
  6  /

Package created.

SQL> create or replace package body pck_test
  2  is
  3   name employee.firstname%type;
  4  
  5   function get return varchar2
  6   is
  7   begin
  8     return name;
  9   end;
 10  
 11   procedure set (x in varchar2)
 12   is
 13   begin
 14     name := x;
 15   end;
 16  
 17  end;
 18  /

Package body created.

SQL> create or replace view param_view
  2  as
  3  select d.name, e.firstname, e.lastname, e.email
  4  from department d left join employee e
  5  on (d.id = e.departmentid
  6  and e.firstname = pck_test.get)
  7  /

View created

SQL> exec pck_test.set('Scott')

PL/SQL procedure completed.

SQL> select * from param_view;

NAME                 FIRSTNAME  LASTNAME             EMAIL                      
-------------------- ---------- -------------------- --------------------       
Department A         Scott      Tiger                xxx@gmail.com              
Department B                                                                    
Department C                                                                    

SQL> exec pck_test.set('Allen')

PL/SQL procedure completed.

SQL> select * from param_view;

NAME                 FIRSTNAME  LASTNAME             EMAIL                      
-------------------- ---------- -------------------- --------------------       
Department A         Allen      Dirk                 yyy@gmail.com              
Department B                                                                    
Department C                                                                    

SQL> select d.name, e.firstname, e.lastname, e.email
  2  from department d left join employee e
  3  on (d.id = e.departmentid)
  4  /

NAME                 FIRSTNAME  LASTNAME             EMAIL                      
-------------------- ---------- -------------------- --------------------       
Department A         Allen      Dirk                 yyy@gmail.com              
Department A         Scott      Tiger                xxx@gmail.com              
Department B                                                                    
Department C
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are simply trying to avoid creating an inner join at the bottom, add a coalesce statement, such as:

```
coalesce(table1.date,'2015-01-28') = '2015-01-28'
```

This will then not create an inner join as all null values will still return.

Answer (score 0):

Deleted original response.
Here is what I come up with

```
create view my_view as
select * from (
select t1.*, t2.*, to_date(null) filter_date from table1 t1 left outer join table2 t2
on t2.id <> t2.id
union all
select t1.*, t2.*, t2.date filter_date from table1 t1 inner outer join table2 t2
on t1.id = t2.id)
```

1. 1st dataset is get all records from t1
2. 2nd dataset is get all records from t1 inner join with t2
   As a result in a query you will always have 1 or 2 records to choose from. If there are 2 records, select one with a date:

   ```
   select * from (
   select *, row_number() over (partition by id order by filter_date NULLS LAST) rnum
   from my_view where filter_date = :date or filter_date is null
   ) where rnum = 1
   ```

or

```
   select * from (
    select *, rownum rnum
    from my_view where filter_date = :date or filter_date is null
    order by filter_date NULLS LAST
    ) where rnum = 1
```

Comment: No, that is not what I need.
This will turn the join into an inner join. I will not get the rows in table1 that doesn't join on a row in table2, because filter_date will be null.

Comment: Yes! you are right, I missed that. Modified select to include "filter_date is null" condition